# Is "reacts and acts upon" correct?

Tags: expressions

I am trying to use the expression:

> 1. A **reacts to and acts upon** B.

The intended meaning is that B influences A ("A reacts to B"), and that A influences B ("A acts upon B"). However, the above expression 1 feels a bit clumsy, so I would like to use something more readable.

I have found several examples of this alternative expression 2 being used. It seems way more readable:

> 2. A **reacts and acts upon** B

Expression 2 is more readable because it uses one common preposition ("upon") for both verbs. However, I am not sure if it is correct. I know that "acts + upon" is a correct combination (it is also used in expression 1). However, I am not sure that "reacts + upon" is a correct combination. Shouldn't one say "reacts + to" as in expression 1? Can "upon" be used with "reacts" in the place of "to", given the meaning of the sentence?

Thank you.

Comment: More context in your text samples would be helpful. It’s almost always the case that context is critical.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any context, but unless you're speaking about a specific field such as chemistry where "react" and "acts upon" might have specific meanings as *terminology* that would be recognised by those within that field, then no - from an everyday grammar perspective, it doesn't sound natural at all.

In everyday language, reciprocal reactions are generally referred to as "*interaction*", for example, "*they interact with each other*". To "*act upon*" something does not generally mean to influence it. For example, "*he acted upon the information*" doesn't mean he affected or influenced the information - it means he used what he learned to do something else.

If you are speaking to a specific field where terminology is used then this question would be better directed to those in that field as it would not be a question about English language.

Comment: @caleb That quote is from a book written in Italian and then translated into English. Perhaps it is a poor translation, or perhaps there was no equivalent English expression for that phrase so they went for a 'gloss' translation (word for word, without any thought to the loss of idiomatic meaning). Your question is here is about speaking or writing in English, and what I said stands.

Comment: @caleb I'm voting to close your question as you are not providing the research.

Comment: @caleb These are all textbooks. As I said in my answer: "If you are speaking to a specific field where terminology is used then this question would be better directed to those in that field as it would not be a question about English language". It might make sense in some very specific contexts, but your question about [x] and [y] is so non-specific I still couldn't say that it is natural and will always make sense.